# Finding the average within a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, average, bootstrap-5

I'm expected to create an html page for a car dealership using JQuery and Bootstrap 5. I'm supposed to use Bootstrap 5 to perform the following:

Create a table with appropriate form input elements that allow the user to enter four (4)
quarterly sales for three (3) sales representatives of a local automobile business. The
figures should be stored in a two-dimensional array. Once the figures are entered, the
program should have a BS5 button to display the following – in the table or below the
table:
− The total sales for each quarter
− The average sales for each sales representative
− The sales representative with the highest sales for each quarter

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#flip").click(function () {
                $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #panel,
        #flip {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
            border: solid 1px white;

        }

        #panel {
            padding: 50px;
            display: none;
        }

        #logo {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 50px;

            .center {
                margin: auto;
                width: 60%;
                border: none;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            quarters = ['Quarter 1', 'Quarter 2', 'Quarter 3', 'Quarter 4'];
            var sales = new Array(3); //Array with 3 rows
            sales[0] = [];
            sales[1] = [];
            sales[2] = [];

            var totalSales = [];

            var s1 = document.getElementsByName('s1[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
                alert("Pushing" + s1[i].value);
                sales[0].push(s1[i].value);
            }

            var s2 = document.getElementsByName('s2[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
                //alert("Pushing"+s2[i].value);
                sales[1].push(s2[i].value);
            }

            var s3 = document.getElementsByName('s3[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
                //alert("Pushing"+s3[i].value);
                sales[2].push(s3[i].value);
            }

            //Total sales for each quarter

            var overall = 0;
            for (var col = 0; col < sales[0].length; ++col) {
                var totalQ = 0;
                for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
                    totalQ += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
                    //alert("sales[row][col]"+sales[row][col]);
                    overall += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
                }
                totalSales.push(totalQ);
                //alert("Candidate\'s Total="+totalVote[col]);
                document.getElementsByName('total[]')[col].value = totalQ;
            }
            alert("Overall=" + overall);

            //Winner in each precinct  
            for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
                highest = parseInt(sales[row][0]);///reset the maximum each time
                //alert(highest);
                for (var col = 0; col < sales[0].length; ++col) {
                    if (parseInt(sales[row][col]) > highest)
                        highest = parseInt(sales[row][col]);
                }
                //alert("Highest votes in row "+(row+1)+"="+highest);
                var repRow = "high" + (row + 1);
                //alert("Precinct="+precinctID);
                document.getElementById(repRow).value = highest;
            }

            //Show winner, votes, and percentage
            //alert("Highest total votes="+ Math.max(...totalVote));
            var currMax = parseInt(totalSales[0]);
            //alert("Initial max="+currMax);
            var maxPos = 0;
            //alert(maxPos);

            for (var i = 0; i < totalSales.length; ++i) {
                if (totalSales[i] > currMax) {
                    currMax = parseInt(totalSales[i]);
                    //alert("CurrentMax="+currMax);
                    maxPos = i;
                }
            }
            //Finding the average sale of each representative
            for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
                var totalperRep = 0; //reset
                for (var col = 0; col < sales.length[0]; ++col) {
                    totalperRep += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
                    var saleRow = "avg" + (row + 1);
                }
                document.getElementById(saleRow).value = totalperRep;
                var average = totalperRep / sales.length[0];
                document.getElementById(average).value = totalperRep;
            }
        }//end function
    </script>
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo/33574391656_af96565fed.jpg" alt="Autolist logo" width="350" height="133"></div>
    <div id="flip"><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Click here to see description </span></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <p>As an automotive dealership, we match our buyers to thousands of used car sites so that you won't even have
            to search.<br>
            From your first car to your fifteenth, we want to make buying and selling a car something you can look
            forward to. We’re taking a data
            driven and user centric approach to create new and better ways to buy and sell cars.
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 style="color:white"><strong>Quarterly Sales</strong></h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="color:white" ;>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dealership</th>
                    <th>Representative</th>
                    <th>Quarter 1</th>
                    <th>Quarter 2</th>
                    <th>Quarter 3</th>
                    <th>Quarter 4</th>
                    <th>Highest sale per rep</th>
                    <th>Average sales per rep </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Carmax in Laurel, MD</td>
                    <td>John Malcavech</td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high1" id="high1" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg1" id="avg1" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>MERCEDES-BENZ OF SILVER SPRING</td>
                    <td>Moses Aran</td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high2" id="high2" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg2" id="avg2" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hertz Car Sales Baltimore</td>
                    <td>Rachet C. Clinton</td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high3" id="high3" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg3" id="avg3" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Sales</td>
                    <td>-----</td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
                    <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
                    <td>-----</td>
                    <td>-----</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="center">
            <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run the above code on a browser, you should see that I was successful in displaying the total sales for each quarter and the sales representative with the highest sales for each quarter.

The part I'm stuck on, however, is finding the average sales of each representative. Whenever, I run the program, no values are displayed in the readonly textbox in the "Average sales per rep" column.

Here's the part of my calculate function that is supposed to find the average sales of each rep:

```
//Finding the average sale of each representative

1 for (var row=0; row<sales.length; ++row)
2 {
3   var totalperRep = 0; //reset
4   
5   for (var col=0; col<sales.length[0]; ++col)
6   {
7       totalperRep += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
8       var saleRow = "avg"+(row+1);
9   
10      
11
12
13  }
14  document.getElementById(saleRow).value = totalperRep;
15      
16      var average = totalperRep/sales.length[0];
17      
18      document.getElementById(average).value = totalperRep;
19     }
```

Lines 1 and 5 represent a row major. It's supposed to allow the program to scan through the sales, one column at a time, and reset totalperRep variable with the current value selected. It should keep adding to the values stored in totalperRep until the row.length and col.length has reached their limit. As shown in line 8, the variable saleRow should call on the Id with the following characters: "avg" and move to the next value in a row. As shown on line 16 the total amount saved in totalperRep should be divided by the sales.length, which should be 4. Because saleRow is calling on the id "avg", and because of document.getElementById(average).value shown on line 18, every element in the table with that id should be displayed in input (readonly) textbox.
For example: <input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg2" id="avg2"

But again, when I run the program, the textboxes under the very last column show up completely blank. I don't understand why that's the case. It should be at least displaying values, if not give me the correct calculations. Can someone please help figure this out, or offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contained a typo: `sales.length[0]` in place of `sales[0].length`.

Once the `totalperRep` is calculated, divide by `4` (the quarters) to obtain the average per sale rep.

Here's a working demo, hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  });
});


function calculate() {
  quarters = ['Quarter 1', 'Quarter 2', 'Quarter 3', 'Quarter 4'];

  var sales = new Array(3); //Array with 3 rows
  sales[0] = [];
  sales[1] = [];
  sales[2] = [];

  var totalSales = [];

  var s1 = document.getElementsByName('s1[]');
  for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    //alert("Pushing" + s1[i].value);
    sales[0].push(s1[i].value);
  }

  var s2 = document.getElementsByName('s2[]');
  for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    //alert("Pushing"+s2[i].value);
    sales[1].push(s2[i].value);


  }

  var s3 = document.getElementsByName('s3[]');
  for (var i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
    //alert("Pushing"+s3[i].value);
    sales[2].push(s3[i].value);
  }


  //Total sales for each quarter

  var overall = 0;
  for (var col = 0; col < sales[0].length; ++col) {
    var totalQ = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
      totalQ += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
      //alert("sales[row][col]"+sales[row][col]);
      overall += parseInt(sales[row][col]);

    }
    totalSales.push(totalQ);
    //alert("Candidate\'s Total="+totalVote[col]);

    document.getElementsByName('total[]')[col].value = totalQ;

  }

  alert("Overall=" + overall);

  //Winner in each precinct  

  for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
    highest = parseInt(sales[row][0]); ///reset the maximum each time
    //alert(highest);
    for (var col = 0; col < sales[0].length; ++col) {
      if (parseInt(sales[row][col]) > highest)
        highest = parseInt(sales[row][col]);
    }
    //alert("Highest votes in row "+(row+1)+"="+highest);
    var repRow = "high" + (row + 1);
    //alert("Precinct="+precinctID);
    document.getElementById(repRow).value = highest;
  }


  //Show winner, votes, and percentage
  //alert("Highest total votes="+ Math.max(...totalVote));
  var currMax = parseInt(totalSales[0]);
  //alert("Initial max="+currMax);
  var maxPos = 0;
  //alert(maxPos);

  for (var i = 0; i < totalSales.length; ++i) {
    if (totalSales[i] > currMax) {
      currMax = parseInt(totalSales[i]);
      //alert("CurrentMax="+currMax);
      maxPos = i;
    }
  }


  //Finding the average sale of each representative


  for (var row = 0; row < sales.length; ++row) {
    var totalperRep = 0; //reset

    for (var col = 0; col < sales[0].length; ++col) {
      totalperRep += parseInt(sales[row][col]);
    }

    var avgRow = "avg" + (row + 1);
    var average = totalperRep / 4; // divide by 4 (quarters)

    document.getElementById(avgRow).value = average;
  }












} //end function
```

```css
  #panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#logo {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 50px;
  .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<body style="background-color: black;">




  <div id="logo"><img src="logo/33574391656_af96565fed.jpg" alt="Autolist logo" width="350" height="133"></div>
  <div id="flip"><span style="font-weight:bold;"> Click here to see description </span></div>
  <div id="panel">
    <p>As an automotive dealership, we match our buyers to thousands of used car sites so that you won't even have to search.<br> From your first car to your fifteenth, we want to make buying and selling a car something you can look forward to. We’re taking
      a data driven and user centric approach to create new and better ways to buy and sell cars.
      <p>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <h2 style="color:white"><strong>Quarterly Sales</strong></h2>

    <table class="table table-bordered" style="color:white" ;>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Dealership</th>
          <th>Representative</th>
          <th>Quarter 1</th>
          <th>Quarter 2</th>
          <th>Quarter 3</th>
          <th>Quarter 4</th>
          <th>Highest sale per rep</th>
          <th>Average sales per rep </th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Carmax in Laurel, MD</td>
          <td>John Malcavech</td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s1[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high1" id="high1" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg1" id="avg1" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>MERCEDES-BENZ OF SILVER SPRING</td>
          <td>Moses Aran</td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s2[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high2" id="high2" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg2" id="avg2" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hertz Car Sales Baltimore</td>
          <td>Rachet C. Clinton</td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="number" name="s3[]"></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="high3" id="high3" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="avg3" id="avg3" readonly></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Total Sales</td>
          <td>-----</td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
          <td><input style="color:red;" type="text" name="total[]" readonly></td>
          <td>-----</td>
          <td>-----</td>
        </tr>



      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="center">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </div>





</body>
```